# How to check whether a row exists using sqlx?

Tags: mysql, go, sqlx

I want this fuction to return true of a row containing the `email` is found in the database. Here is the code

```
func UserExists(email string) bool {
    var err error
    user := model.User{}
    err = shared.Dbmap.Get(&user, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=? LIMIT 1", email)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("User is already in DB")
        return true
    } else {
        fmt.Println("No rows returned")
        return false
    }
}
```

However, it always returns `false` even if there is such email in the db, so clearly the query is not up to the job. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing fmt.Println with fmt.Printf("%v", err) to make sure you're getting the error you think you're getting?

Comment: Check the number of rows in the result.

Comment: @ipaul I get this error: `sql: Scan error on column index 4: unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *time.Time
`

Comment: @Karlom what is the variable name that reference to the DB object, is it shared ?

Comment: @Karlom that looks like an issue between how your database encodes timestamps and how the timestamp is defined in your model.  Maybe related to https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/29?

Comment: @ipaul, yes, actually I resolved it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040319/unsupported-scan-storing-driver-value-type-uint8-into-type-time-time. You can answer and I'll accept. Thanks for your tip.

Comment: To check if it returns no rows this would help  ```err == sql.ErrNoRows```